# Error Loading Project: Visual C# 2015 compiler could not be created

Tags: windows, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition in Windows 10 Professional(64 bit).
[image: Visual Studio Version Information]
Today I installed the [new Visual Studio Update 3](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2015-update3-vs) and now I am getting this error

> E:\path_to_solution_folder\ProjectName.Web.csproj : error  :
>
> Project 'ProjectName.Web' could not be opened because the Visual C# 2015 compiler could not be created. An exception was thrown while initializing part "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.DiagnosticAnalyzerService".

Googled a bit, and got a solution from this website,

Link: [Fixing Visual Studio 2015 after update 3](http://vimvq1987.com/2016/07/fixing-visual-studio-2015-update-3/)

So as per the article, I added `System.Reflection.Metadata.dll` to GAC.
[image: System.Reflection.Metadata in GAC]

Now when I try to run my project or open a controller the IDE *still* restarts! Went to the event logger and found out this.

> **Application**: devenv.exe
> **Framework Version**: v4.0.30319
> **Description**: The application requested process termination through System.Environment.FailFast(string message).
>
> **Message**: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Reflection.Metadata, Version=1.0.21.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. File name: 'System.Reflection.Metadata, Version=1.0.21.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' ...

**Details**

```html
Log Name:      Application
Source:        .NET Runtime
Date:          25-Jul-16 9:29:13 PM
Event ID:      1025
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      Lenovo
Description:
Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The application requested process termination through System.Environment.FailFast(string message).
Message: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Reflection.Metadata, Version=1.0.21.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Reflection.Metadata, Version=1.0.21.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpCompilationFactoryService.Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Host.ICompilationFactoryService.CreateCompilation(String assemblyName, CompilationOptions options)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Solution.CompilationTracker.CreateEmptyCompilation()
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Solution.CompilationTracker.<BuildDeclarationCompilationFromScratchAsync>d__24.MoveNext()

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Stack:
   at System.Environment.FailFast(System.String, System.Exception)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FailFast.OnFatalException(System.Exception)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ErrorReporting.FatalError.Report(System.Exception, System.Action`1<System.Exception>)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ErrorReporting.FatalError.ReportUnlessCanceled(System.Exception)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Solution+CompilationTracker+<BuildDeclarationCompilationFromScratchAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpCompilationFactoryService.Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Host.ICompilationFactoryService.CreateCompilation(System.String, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CompilationOptions)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Solution+CompilationTracker.CreateEmptyCompilation()
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Solution+CompilationTracker+<BuildDeclarationCompilationFromScratchAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Start[[Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Solution+CompilationTracker+<BuildDeclarationCompilationFromScratchAsync>d__24, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]](<BuildDeclarationCompilationFromScratchAsync>d__24 ByRef)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Solution+CompilationTracker.BuildDeclarationCompilationFromScratchAsync(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Solution, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Solution+CompilationTracker+<BuildCompilationFromScratchAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Start[[Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Solution+CompilationTracker+<BuildCompilationFromScratchAsync>d__23, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]](<BuildCompilationFromScratchAsync>d__23 ByRef)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Solution+CompilationTracker.BuildCompilationFromScratchAsync(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Solution, State, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Solution+CompilationTracker.BuildCompilationAsync(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Solution, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Solution+CompilationTracker+<GetOrBuildCompilationAsync>d__21.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Start[[Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Solution+CompilationTracker+<GetOrBuildCompilationAsync>d__21, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]](<GetOrBuildCompilationAsync>d__21 ByRef)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Solution+CompilationTracker.GetOrBuildCompilationAsync(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Solution, Boolean, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Solution.GetCompilationAsync(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Project, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Document+<GetSemanticModelAsync>d__21.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Start[[Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Document+<GetSemanticModelAsync>d__21, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]](<GetSemanticModelAsync>d__21 ByRef)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Document.GetSemanticModelAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.CSharp.NavigationBar.CSharpNavigationBarItemService+<GetTypesInFileAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Start[[Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.CSharp.NavigationBar.CSharpNavigationBarItemService+<GetTypesInFileAsync>d__3, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.EditorFeatures, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]](<GetTypesInFileAsync>d__3 ByRef)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.CSharp.NavigationBar.CSharpNavigationBarItemService.GetTypesInFileAsync(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Document, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.CSharp.NavigationBar.CSharpNavigationBarItemService+<GetItemsAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Start[[Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.CSharp.NavigationBar.CSharpNavigationBarItemService+<GetItemsAsync>d__1, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.EditorFeatures, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]](<GetItemsAsync>d__1 ByRef)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.CSharp.NavigationBar.CSharpNavigationBarItemService.GetItemsAsync(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Document, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.NavigationBar.NavigationBarController+<ComputeModelAsync>d__30.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Start[[Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.NavigationBar.NavigationBarController+<ComputeModelAsync>d__30, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]](<ComputeModelAsync>d__30 ByRef)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.NavigationBar.NavigationBarController.ComputeModelAsync(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Document, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.ITextSnapshot, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.NavigationBar.NavigationBarController+<>c__DisplayClass29_0.<StartModelUpdateAndSelectedItemUpdateTasks>b__0(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromTask`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecutionContextCallback(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()

Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name=".NET Runtime" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1025</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-07-25T15:59:13.647712200Z" />
    <EventRecordID>8082</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>Lenovo</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The application requested process termination through System.Environment.FailFast(string message).
Message: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Reflection.Metadata, Version=1.0.21.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Reflection.Metadata, Version=1.0.21.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpCompilationFactoryService.Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Host.ICompilationFactoryService.CreateCompilation(String assemblyName, CompilationOptions options)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Solution.CompilationTracker.CreateEmptyCompilation()
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Solution.CompilationTracker.&lt;BuildDeclarationCompilationFromScratchAsync&gt;d__24.MoveNext()

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Stack:
   at System.Environment.FailFast(System.String, System.Exception)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FailFast.OnFatalException(System.Exception)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ErrorReporting.FatalError.Report(System.Exception, System.Action`1&lt;System.Exception&gt;)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ErrorReporting.FatalError.ReportUnlessCanceled(System.Exception)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Solution+CompilationTracker+&lt;BuildDeclarationCompilationFromScratchAsync&gt;d__24.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpCompilationFactoryService.Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Host.ICompilationFactoryService.CreateCompilation(System.String, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CompilationOptions)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Solution+CompilationTracker.CreateEmptyCompilation()
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Solution+CompilationTracker+&lt;BuildDeclarationCompilationFromScratchAsync&gt;d__24.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Start[[Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Solution+CompilationTracker+&lt;BuildDeclarationCompilationFromScratchAsync&gt;d__24, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]](&lt;BuildDeclarationCompilationFromScratchAsync&gt;d__24 ByRef)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Solution+CompilationTracker.BuildDeclarationCompilationFromScratchAsync(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Solution, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Solution+CompilationTracker+&lt;BuildCompilationFromScratchAsync&gt;d__23.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Start[[Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Solution+CompilationTracker+&lt;BuildCompilationFromScratchAsync&gt;d__23, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]](&lt;BuildCompilationFromScratchAsync&gt;d__23 ByRef)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Solution+CompilationTracker.BuildCompilationFromScratchAsync(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Solution, State, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Solution+CompilationTracker.BuildCompilationAsync(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Solution, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Solution+CompilationTracker+&lt;GetOrBuildCompilationAsync&gt;d__21.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Start[[Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Solution+CompilationTracker+&lt;GetOrBuildCompilationAsync&gt;d__21, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]](&lt;GetOrBuildCompilationAsync&gt;d__21 ByRef)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Solution+CompilationTracker.GetOrBuildCompilationAsync(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Solution, Boolean, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Solution.GetCompilationAsync(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Project, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Document+&lt;GetSemanticModelAsync&gt;d__21.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Start[[Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Document+&lt;GetSemanticModelAsync&gt;d__21, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]](&lt;GetSemanticModelAsync&gt;d__21 ByRef)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Document.GetSemanticModelAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.CSharp.NavigationBar.CSharpNavigationBarItemService+&lt;GetTypesInFileAsync&gt;d__3.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Start[[Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.CSharp.NavigationBar.CSharpNavigationBarItemService+&lt;GetTypesInFileAsync&gt;d__3, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.EditorFeatures, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]](&lt;GetTypesInFileAsync&gt;d__3 ByRef)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.CSharp.NavigationBar.CSharpNavigationBarItemService.GetTypesInFileAsync(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Document, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.CSharp.NavigationBar.CSharpNavigationBarItemService+&lt;GetItemsAsync&gt;d__1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Start[[Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.CSharp.NavigationBar.CSharpNavigationBarItemService+&lt;GetItemsAsync&gt;d__1, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.EditorFeatures, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]](&lt;GetItemsAsync&gt;d__1 ByRef)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.CSharp.NavigationBar.CSharpNavigationBarItemService.GetItemsAsync(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Document, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.NavigationBar.NavigationBarController+&lt;ComputeModelAsync&gt;d__30.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Start[[Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.NavigationBar.NavigationBarController+&lt;ComputeModelAsync&gt;d__30, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]](&lt;ComputeModelAsync&gt;d__30 ByRef)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.NavigationBar.NavigationBarController.ComputeModelAsync(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Document, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.ITextSnapshot, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.NavigationBar.NavigationBarController+&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass29_0.&lt;StartModelUpdateAndSelectedItemUpdateTasks&gt;b__0(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromTask`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecutionContextCallback(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: The blog post talks about version 1.2.0.0, not your problem.  1.0.21.0 smells like a .NETCore version number, not stored in the GAC.  Whatever you did previously with the various betas and rcs is likely to be relevant.  Tends to be the kind of version mess always associated with betas, installing from scratch is often the only recourse.

Comment: umm... I wont be sure about the blog post not related altogether. for one, the trouble started with update. also the same dll is the culprit. cant think about reinstalling. i didnt even had an rc installed so that the ide wont crash. reinstalling will be my last option :(

Comment: @naveen, Did you find solutions? I have the same problem.